# Stop program from closing in python

Tags: python, windows, cmd, exe

So I made a program that uses the pyautogui module to type "Hello" over and over again in a while loop and press enter. It's not a console output. It works perfectly fine when I launch it from the pycharm editor but when I open it from the folder or convert to an exe it just closes instantly. Why does the program close when I try opening it from the file explorer or after converting it to an exe?
I'm new to python, thanks for any help!

```
import pyautogui
import time

message = "Hello"

time.sleep(5)

while True:
    pyautogui.typewrite(message)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    time.sleep(37)
```

After pressing Run I have 5 seconds to switch to a notepad and it will start typing "Hello" and enter every 37 seconds.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I have added a simpler version of my code to the post.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same problem on a Mac, you need to go to your security preferences.
`Settings > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility`
and allow that specific application to access your computer by pressing the `+` icon. However, in the question, you stated that you are using `.exe` files, so I will assume you are on Windows. I don't use Windows, but for people reading this question in the future on Mac, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved the problem!!

I ran my python script via the windows command prompt. The error it showed me was an error with a module named pyautogui. The problem was that my module was installed with the wrong version. Using "pip3" instead of "pip" install pyautogui fixed the problem for me and now I can open and use my script directly from the file explorer.